# flutter ffi breaks web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, ffi

I am using dart ffi in my project. Some plugins I use are also using ffi.

When I try to build my app for web I get an error below.

```
Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';                                                      
       ^                                                                
../../../../Library/Flutter/sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-1.0.0/lib/src/utf8.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';                                                      
       ^                                                                
../../../../Library/Flutter/sdk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-1.0.0/lib/src/utf16.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi'
import 'dart:ffi';
```

I undertand ffi has no scope in web, but how do I make sure it's ignored and still compiling for web.